# Проблема с дополенеием Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, opera

Разрабатываю расширения для Chrome (Opera and Yandex). Появилась ошибка в консоли "popup.js:11 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null". Дополнение работает, но с ошибкой.

Popup.js

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var btnGetKeyWord = document.getElementById('btnGetKeyWord');
var lblFeedback = document.getElementById('lblFeedback');
var txtResult = document.getElementById('txtResult');
var btnCopy = document.getElementById('btnCopy');

// Get Keyword
btnGetKeyWord.onclick = function () {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, { method: "getTag" }, function (response) {
            if (response == undefined || response.method !== "getTag" || response.data == '') {
                lblFeedback.innerText = 'Keywords not found. Select the English language site and try again';
                lblFeedback.className = "alert alert-danger";
                return;
            }

            txtResult.innerText = response.data;
            lblFeedback.innerText = 'Found ' + response.count + ' key words.';
            lblFeedback.className = "alert alert-success";
        });
    });
};
// Function Copy
btnCopy.onclick = function () {
    if (txtResult.innerText.indexOf('How to Use') !== -1) {
        lblFeedback.innerText = 'Active when keyword is detected.';
        lblFeedback.className = "alert alert-danger";
        return;
    }

    if (lblFeedback.innerText.indexOf('Copied') == -1 && lblFeedback.innerText.indexOf('Not found words.') === -1) {
        lblFeedback.innerText = lblFeedback.innerText + ' Copied!';
        lblFeedback.className = "alert alert-success";
    }

    txtResult.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
};

});
```

Посмотреть все файлы дополнения можно вот здесь https://github.com/blinovartem/kw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш [manifest](https://github.com/blinovartem/kw/blob/master/manifest.json) файл содержит следующие строки:

```
...
"background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]  // Автоматическая перезагрузка расширения
}
```

То есть вы используете скрипт popup.js на background-странице. 
А указанных кнопок там просто не существует, о чем вам и сообщает `getElementById` возвращая `null`.

*P.S. Совет: воздержитесь от использования комментариев в JSON. Стандарт не поддерживает их наличие.*

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь. Отличный совет